# What should I do to write in a selectInput() in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I did a `selectInput()` in Shiny, like this:

```
              box(selectInput("reg_cnae", "Por Região:", 
                              c("Todas",str_sort(unique(as.character(Coop_ativas$regiao)))),
                              selected = "Todos")),
```

But, in this selection, I have 27 options. How can I configure it, so I can write and it gives me the item? Instead of I need to scroll down by all items.

Comment: Go to https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-examples.html, click in the "2. Multi-select" input widget, and start typing a US state name, demonstrating that you can start typing. Bottom line: you can use `selectizeInput`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click inside the selectInput, then hit backspace, you should be able to type for the choice rather than looking through the dropdown. The other option would be to use a selectizeInput with a null inital value and a placeholder.

```
selectizeInput("reg_cnae", "Por Região:", 
               choices = c("Todas",str_sort(unique(as.character(Coop_ativas$regiao)))), 
               options = list(
                 placeholder = 'Type here',
                 onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
               ))
```